# Question about cost optimization formula for SELECT

Tags: optimization, database-theory

I am a student in computer science and I have a question, which refers to cost optimization. I have to read the book (Fundamentals of Database Systems from Elmasry and Navathe) and try to present the topic to class. But I have some issues understanding one cost formula for B-tree-index:

> Using a secondary (B+-tree) index: [...]If the comparison condition is
>   (> >=, <, <=) and half the file records are assumed to satisfy the condition, then(very roughly) half of the first level index blocks are
>   accessed, plus half the file records via the index. The cost estimate
>   for this case, approximately, is C=x+(b_l1/2)+(r/2).[...]
>
> Using Linear search: [...] C=b[...]

where

```
x = number of levels of multilevel index
r = number of records
b = number of blocks
b_li = number of first-level index blocks
C = cost function
```

I don't understand the formula for the secondary index. I think the formula should look like this:

> C=x+(b_l1/2)+(b/2)

Can somebody explain me, why the formula uses the number of entries instead of number of blocks?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "first level" means the leaf level of a nonclustered (secondary) index, the `b_li/2` part accounts for the cost of scanning (using sequential I/O) through half those index blocks.

Assuming "file records" means the base table, the `r/2` component represents the cost of looking up additional data not present in the secondary index. Since this is a per-row cost that is expected to result in a random I/O pattern, it makes sense to express this in terms of `r`.